# how to load and execute java commands from a text file

Tags: java, command-line, java.util.scanner, java-io, file-io

I am new to coding Java and am in need of some advice.

I am coding a small program that draws shapes in the graphics panel as specified from the users console input. (using the scanner class)

For examples the user may type `move 100 100` to move the graphics 'pen' to the x,y points,
or may type `line 100 200` to draw a line between the two co-ordinates,
or may type 'circle 50' to draw a circle with radius 50px

My next goal is to include the command 'load example.txt' to load a text file (example.txt) containing a few commands that will then be executed onto the graphics panel.

I have been told the best way to do this is using

```
processCommandLine(String commandLine);
```

I have been browsing the internet for a long time now looking for some helpful information but so far all i can find is how to read from a text file, many like this:

```
 Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("example.txt");
```

I know I need to use the Scanner class to read the file contents and then (I think using the processCommandLine method) execute them on the graphics panel

My code so far:  (I have called all necessary classes and methods saved in a separate file)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign1 {

   public final static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Let's draw something on the screen!");

      GraphicsScreen graphics = new GraphicsScreen();

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // used to read the keyboard

      String next; // stores the next line input
      String[] one;

      do {
         System.out.print("Enter a command (\"stop\") to finish : ");
         System.out.print("Type 'help' for a list of commands ");
         next = input.nextLine();
         one = next.split(" ");

         String command = one[0];

         if (next.contains("help")) {
            System.out
                  .println("Type 'move' followed by an X and Y co-ordinate to move the graphical pointer.");
            System.out
                  .println("Type 'circle' followed by a radius value to output a circle.");
            System.out
                  .println("Type 'line' followed by an X and Y co-ordinate to draw a line.");
            System.out.println("Type 'clear' to reset the graphical canvas.");
         }

         else if (next.contains("move")) {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            x = Integer.parseInt(one[1]);
            y = Integer.parseInt(one[2]);

            graphics.moveTo(x, y);
         }

         else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("circle")) {
            int radius = 0;
            radius = Integer.parseInt(one[1]);
            graphics.circle(radius);

         }

         else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("line")) {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            x = Integer.parseInt(one[1]);
            y = Integer.parseInt(one[2]);

            graphics.lineTo(x, y);

         }

         else if (next.contains("clear")) {
            graphics.clear();
         }

         else {
            System.out.println("error message");
         }

      } while (next.equalsIgnoreCase("stop") == false);

      System.out
            .println("You have decided to stop entering commands. Program terminated!");

      graphics.close();
   }
}
```

I need the text file to contain, for example :

```
move 100 100
circle 50
line 100 200
```

and when I call the operation 'load example.txt' this text file will be read by the application and the commands in it executed by drawing the specified shapes on the graphics canvas.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated, I've been doing Java programming less than a year and am always trying to improve, so any constructive criticism is welcome.

Comment: Is there something that doesn't work? Do you have a specific problem? It's difficult to understand exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: im trying to create the command 'load' that will load commands from a text file eg if the user types 'load example.txt'

the commands in the text file will then be read and executed on the console.

the commands are graphics.draw commands that render user input specified shapes onto a graphical canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this is a nice project because it introduces you to the concept of code reuse and rudimentary MVC (model-view-controller) programming. Basically, if you consider that the graphical context is your view, and that you are *controlling* access to this view using a set of commands, then your model is obviously the command itself. What you are trying to do now is make it possible to supply models from an alternate source, keeping everything else in your program intact.

So, your first task is to create this reusable 'controller' code, that knows how to take a model (the command), and use it to affect the view (your graphics context). You already have all the necessary logic, you just need to move it into your desired function:

```
public static void processCommandLine(String[] commandArgs, GraphicsScreen graphics) {
   if (commandArgs == null || commandArgs.length = 0 || commandArgs[0] == null) {
      System.out.println("Null command!");
   }

   String command = commandArgs[0];

   if (command.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("move")) {
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;

      x = Integer.parseInt(commandArgs[1]);
      y = Integer.parseInt(commandArgs[2]);

      graphics.moveTo(x, y);
   }

   else if (command.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("circle")) {
      int radius = Integer.parseInt(one[1]);
      graphics.circle(radius);

   }

   else if (command.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("line")) {
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;

      x = Integer.parseInt(commandArgs[1]);
      y = Integer.parseInt(comamndArgs[2]);

      graphics.lineTo(x, y);
   }

   else if (command.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("clear")) {
      graphics.clear();
   }
   else {
      System.out.println("Invalid Command!");
   }
}
```

With this, you can pass a command and a graphics screen to a single function, and it will 'render' the command. Now, you want to provide different *ways* of accessing the function. Your first access method is to query the user, via console, for a command and then to execute it. But you also want to be able to load up multiple commands from a file and run them all at once. So define a method to read a bunch of commands from a file:

```
public static List<String> getCommands(String fileName) {
   if(fileName == null) return new ArrayList<String>(0);

   File file = new File(fileName);
   if(! (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
      System.err.println("Cannot access file! Non-existent or read access restricted");
      return new ArrayList<String>(0);
   }

   List<String> commandLines = new ArrayList<String>(32);
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
   while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      commandLines.add(scanner.nextLine());
   }

   scanner.close();

   return commandLines;
}
```

And now, you just need to alter how you are piping commands to your render function, depending on wether the source of commands is the console, or a file:

```
public final static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("Let's draw something on the screen!");

   GraphicsScreen graphics = new GraphicsScreen();

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // used to read the keyboard

   String next; // stores the next line input
   String[] one;

   do {
      System.out.print("Enter a command (\"stop\") to finish : ");
      System.out.print("Type 'help' for a list of commands ");
      next = input.nextLine();
      one = next.split(" ");

      String command = one[0];

      if (command.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("help")) {
         System.out
               .println("Type 'move' followed by an X and Y co-ordinate to move the graphical pointer.");
         System.out
               .println("Type 'circle' followed by a radius value to output a circle.");
         System.out
               .println("Type 'line' followed by an X and Y co-ordinate to draw a line.");
         System.out.println("Type 'clear' to reset the graphical canvas.");
      }

      else if (command.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("load")) {
         List<String> commandLines = getCommands(one[1]);
         for (String commandLine : commandLines) {
            String[] commandArgs = commandLine.split(" ");
            processCommandLine(commandArgs, graphics);
         }
      }

      else if (command.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
         break;
      }

      else {
         processCommandLine(one, graphics);
      }
   } while (true);

   System.out
         .println("You have decided to stop entering commands. Program terminated!");
   graphics.close();
}
```

With these (minor) changes, you now have a way to obtain commands from multiple different sources, and have those commands rendered to your view.